# C#, ReportViewer: How to make Report Path a URL parameter

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

I am working on a solution that uses Report Viewer to access SSRS reports in our server.
Currently the server URL and the repot path, are values stored in the Web.config file.

```
Web.config  

    <add key="ReportServerUrl" value="https://sqlssrs/reportserver"/>
    <add key="ReportPath" value="/group/type/report-name"/>
```

Then these values are mapped in the ReportViewer.aspx.cs code behind.

```
ReportViewer.aspx.cs

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {

                // Add the Reporting Server URL  
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"].ToString());

                //Add the Report Path
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPath"].ToString();

                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I was asked to try to make a change that will allows us to pass the Report Path value, as a query string parameter.

I am not sure how to accomplish this task. I tried to do the following.

```
 rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://sqlssrs/reportserver?pReportPath=/group/type/report-name");

 rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl).Get("pReportPath");
```

That code does not work. It gives me an error that reads.

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'string'
```

Would it be possible to get some instruction on how to be able to accomplish this task?
I am running the report within Visual Studio 2015, I am thinking I also need to set the URL in the project configuration, but I am not sure about that either.

I appreciate any direction on how to program this, any articles, examples, whatever can aid me to complete this task.

Thank you for sharing your experience.

Erasmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.QueryString["pReportPath"]` to retrieve the query value.

Try:

```cs
// Add the Reporting Server URL  
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"].ToString());

//Add the Report Path
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["pReportPath"];
```

Then navigate your browser to `ReportViewer.aspx?pReportPath=/group/type/report-name`

Answer (score 1):

Report server should contain the URL and the path should contain the path starting with '/'.

I think the correct way to do this is  :

rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://sqlssrs/reportserver");
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath= "/group/type/report-name"

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252075(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#how-to-configure-reportviewer-for-remote-processing

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ashish. How would I program the ReportPath, to be assigned from a query string parameter? Is it doable? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use ReportParameter class.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameter?view=sqlserver-2016